# create a VPD like file in specman

Tags: specman

I want to dump during a specman simulation data about my test environment (like structs and vars). 
I know such option exists in vcs runs (the creation of a VPD file), but I can't find a similar option in specman. 
could you please assist?

Comment: [Debussy/Verdi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novas_Software) has an option for tracing Specman, but I've never used it.  Others in my group have used it and I have seen the output.  It is exactly what you want, if you have a license for that exquisite tool.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the "wave" commands in the Specman reference manual.
They allow you to dump Specman information (structs, primitive types, events, etc.) onto the waveform.
Specman supports different waveform tools - Simvision has native and the most extensive support, but Specman can also work with Synopsys DVE, MTI Modelsim and Novas Verdi.